# How to take values from .CSV and set them to a double?

Tags: android, csv

I have been stuck on this problem for a few days and cannot find any help online. I want to take specific values from a .CSV depending on the user's location. My .CSV looks something like this:

```
State,Value
California,0.85
Arizona,0.95
New York,0.75
etc...
```

The app currently tracks the user's state and sets it to local like so:

```
final String local = address.get(0).getAdminArea();
```

I am trying to find a way to have the app look through the .CSV and find the row when local=[state] then take the value from the second column and set it to a double. I have no clue where to start and could really use any help anyone can provide! Thank you!

Just to clarify, I am not trying to print the .CSV, I only need to extract a single value.

**Edit:**
I solved the issue by using a buffered reader and reading the values into a HashMap then calling the correct key based on location.

Comment: If your csv format is fixed and you know it will always be State,Value. Then create a map and the key will be the first value and the value of the map the second value in the csv and so on. Then you can query the map and get the data you want.

Comment: Could you possibly provide a link to an example/tutorial of this?

Comment: hope you know about java beans and mapping, this library should make things easier for you https://github.com/teabow/android-csv-reader

Comment: Thank you for providing this link. This is very useful and I am finally getting somewhere. However I do not know where I put in the test for checking for user location=state then parsing the related value?

Comment: if you see that link, you have to create a bean to which you csv will be mapped and then saved in a collection. Now this collection has the data in State<->Value format, so you need to iterate this collection and keep checking if state is = location, assuming you already know the location.

Comment: I solved my issue. By using a buffered reader and setting the values into a HashMap I was able to complete the task. Thank you.

Comment: cool, post it as an answer so that i will help others, cheers!